# What is the best way to write specs for code that depends on environment variables?

Tags: ruby, rspec, environment-variables

I am testing some code that pulls its configuration from environment variables (set by Heroku config vars in production, for local development I use foreman).

What's the best way to test this kind of code with RSpec?

I came up with this:

```
before :each do
    ENV.stub(:[]).with("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID").and_return("asdf")
    ENV.stub(:[]).with("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY").and_return("secret")
end
```

If you don't need to test different values of the environment variables, I guess you could set them in `spec_helper` instead.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: This works the same with Mocha: `ENV.stubs(:[]).with("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID").returns("asdf")`

Comment: @jeradg, but you can't access any other variable in this way :/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That would work.

Another way would be to put a layer of indirection between your code and the environment variables, like some sort of configuration object that's easy to mock.

Comment: If this is in Rails you already have its own configuration object to add to if you want.

Comment: That is a handy tip. I did not know you could define your own configuration options so easily. Just do this in environments/*.rb: `config.my_config_value = 'value'` and it will be made available as `Rails.configuration.my_config_value`.

Answer (score 98):

You also can stub the constant:

```
stub_const('ENV', {'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID' => 'asdf'})
```

Or, if you still want the rest of the ENV:

```
stub_const('ENV', ENV.to_hash.merge('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID' => 'asdf'))
```

Comment: `ENV` doesn't appear to have a `merge` method (at least in Ruby 1.9.3).

Comment: This is the best approach for a quick env stubs, but in second case you need `ENV.to_hash` to preserve original env.

Comment: Making the hash keys double quoted made it work for me. When i had the keys with single quotes, they got converted to :symbols. Ex: :AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

Answer (score 10):

This syntax works for me:

```
module SetEnvVariable

  def set_env_var(name, value)
   # Old Syntax
   # ENV.stub(:[])
   # ENV.stub(:[]).with(name).and_return(value)

   allow(ENV).to receive(:[]) # stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.
   allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with(name).and_return(value)
  end

end
```

Comment: won't work if you use e.g., `fetch` for `ENV` access.

Comment: add a couple more lines for fetch:
`allow(ENV).to receive(:fetch).with(name).and_return(value)`

Answer (score 8):

As [Heroku suggests](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local_setup), you can use Foreman's `.env` file to store environment variables for development.

If you do that, you can use `foreman run` to run your specs:

```
foreman run bundle exec rspec spec
```

Comment: It does not help if you want to test outcomes of different values in the same env variable.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) to setup your environment during tests but need to **modify an env variable for a specific test** then following approach can be useful.

A simpler method than stubbing `ENV` is to replace the environment for the duration of the test, and then restore it afterwards like so:

```
with_environment("FOO" => "baz") do
  puts ENV.fetch("FOO")
end
```

Using a helper like this:

```
module EnvironmentHelper
  def with_environment(replacement_env)
    original_env = ENV.to_hash
    ENV.update(replacement_env)

    yield
  ensure
    ENV.replace(original_env)
  end
end
```

By using `ensure` the original environment is restored even if the test fails.

There's a handy comparison of methods for [setting & modifying environment variables during tests](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/testing-and-environment-variables) including stubbing the `ENV`, replacing values before / after the test, and gems like ClimateControl.

Comment: This is probably the cleanest answer I've seen here. I'd use it with an `around` block for it to be completely idiomatic.

Answer (score 5):

I'd avoid `ENV.stub(:[])` - it does not work if other things are using `ENV` such as pry(you'll get an error about needing to stub `DISABLE_PRY`).

`#stub_const` works well as already pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://github.com/littleowllabs/stub_env to achieve this. It allows you to stub individual environment variables without stubbing all of them as your solution suggested.

Install the gem then write

```
before :each do
  stub_env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'asdf')
  stub_env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY','secret')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

Running tests under foreman, as @ciastek suggests, works great when running specs from CLI.  But that doesn't help me run specs with Ruby Test in Sublime Text 2. Dotenv does exactly what you, transparently.