# Is it possible to change Rails ENV in ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

ENV variable values are set in config/application.yml in a rails app. is it possible to change only for specific test case in ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest? Something like this:

```
class DummyTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  context '...' do
    it '...' do
      ENV['API_URL'] = ...
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to change anything. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've missed [creating-rails-environments](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#creating-rails-environments) of the configuration on the Rails documentation.

This should solve your issue without monkey patching anything on your specs.

I would also suggest to use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem which help you with environment variables. In your case you'll have at least those files:

- .env.development
- .env.test

If you really want to update a value for a specific test, I would suggest to stub it like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19951660)

Comment: oh yes, I know it is possible to have multiple environments in the configuration. but in this case, I have an environment variable value that I only want to be applied on this specific testcase instead of the whole test environment. not sure if its the best approach though

Comment: Oh ok. Let me update my answer.